# Right-Handed Euler Angles XYZ to Left-Handed Euler Angles XYZ

Tags: 3d, rotation, geometry, coordinate-systems, euler-angles

I'm sure this is simple, but have not had any success researching this and getting a successful answer.

I have rotations defined as three euler angles, in XYZ order, right-handed.

I have to convert to a left-handed system of Euler XYZ.  How do I adjust these angles to be correct for a left-handed system?

Also if anyone has any samples, so I can ensure doing it right, such as what does 90 -45 160 or 90 40 30 go to.

Comment: Wikipedia should be a reliable source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: The concept of "right/left-handed" does not define a specific coordinate system. It's only a property of such a system.
For your question you need to specify transformation beetwen two systems, i.e. how do you calculate point coordinates x',y',z' from x,y,z ?

Comment: For Left handed, X right, Y up, Z forward, for right handed, I have X right, Y up, Z away.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Notation:

```
x,y,z - old system basis
x',y',z' - new system basis

Transformation between systems:
x' = x
y' = y
z' = -z

Euler angles:
EulerXYZ = (alfa,beta,gamma)
EulerXYZ' = (alfa',beta',gamma') = ?
```

Now I can think of two ways to solve it:

### Graphically

1. Draw both systems
2. Mark positive rotation on the right-handed one using right-hand rule
3. Mark positive rotation on the left-handed one using left-hand rule
4. When the rotation on corresponding axes agree then conversion is `angle' = angle` otherwise is `angle' = -angle`

[image: right and left handes system with positive rotation marked]

In the picture above `#1` is right-handed and `#2` is left-handed system (the red line always passes over the black line).

Looking at the picture we can conclude that 
`alfa',beta',gamma' = -alfa,-beta,+gamma`

### Algebraically

Conversion can be calculated using geometric algebra. It is somehow similar to 
quaternions but rotation takes place "in oriented plane" instead of "around axis".

Oriented plane is defined by product of two vectors `u^v` and have following property: `-(u^v) = (-u)^v = u^(-v)`

Rotation is defined by rotor `R(angle, plane)` and `R(angle, -plane) = R(-angle, plane)`

Now:

```
R(alfa, y^z) = R(-alfa, -(y^z)) = R(-alfa, y^(-z)) = R(-alfa, y'^z')
R(beta, x^z) = R(-beta, x'^z')
R(gamma, x^y) = R(+gamma, x'^y')
```

so

```
alfa',beta',gamma' = -alfa,-beta,+gamma
```

Comment: I feel like this is an under appreciated gem of an answer.

Comment: Just want to be clear, are we talking about extrinsic rotation?

Comment: @vickyLin It works for both intrinsic and extrinsic rotation.

Comment: But intrinsic rotation will change rotation axis when doing rotation. How does it make sense according to "solve it **Graphically**"?

Comment: @vickyLin We are not applying rotation. This question is about converting angles between two coordinate systems. Those angles can describe different intrinsic or extrinsic rotations. The proper conversion ensures that the effect of some particular rotation will be the same in both coordinate systems.

Comment: This answer is simply perfect. Ty